# Convert ts object into a human readable time format

Tags: r, datetime

I have two time series

```
x1<- seq(
     from=as.POSIXct("2020-08-25 18:20:21 CEST", tz="UTC"),
     to=as.POSIXct("2020-08-25 18:41:21 CEST", tz="UTC"),
     by="min"
   )  
x2<- seq(
     from=as.POSIXct("2020-08-25 18:20:46 CEST", tz="UTC"),
     to=as.POSIXct("2020-08-25 18:41:46 CEST", tz="UTC"),
     by="min"
   )
```

which I want to combine:

```
x3<- rbind(x1, x2)
> x3
         [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]       [,6]       [,7]       [,8]       [,9]      [,10]      [,11]      [,12]      [,13]
x1 1598379621 1598379681 1598379741 1598379801 1598379861 1598379921 1598379981 1598380041 1598380101 1598380161 1598380221 1598380281 1598380341
x2 1598379646 1598379706 1598379766 1598379826 1598379886 1598379946 1598380006 1598380066 1598380126 1598380186 1598380246 1598380306 1598380366
        [,14]      [,15]      [,16]      [,17]      [,18]      [,19]      [,20]      [,21]      [,22]
x1 1598380401 1598380461 1598380521 1598380581 1598380641 1598380701 1598380761 1598380821 1598380881
x2 1598380426 1598380486 1598380546 1598380606 1598380666 1598380726 1598380786 1598380846 1598380906
```

or via

```
x3<- ts(c(x1, x2),
   start = start(x1),
   frequency = frequency(x1))
> x3
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 44 
Frequency = 1 
 [1] 1598379621 1598379681 1598379741 1598379801 1598379861 1598379921 1598379981 1598380041 1598380101 1598380161 1598380221 1598380281 1598380341
[14] 1598380401 1598380461 1598380521 1598380581 1598380641 1598380701 1598380761 1598380821 1598380881 1598379646 1598379706 1598379766 1598379826
[27] 1598379886 1598379946 1598380006 1598380066 1598380126 1598380186 1598380246 1598380306 1598380366 1598380426 1598380486 1598380546 1598380606
[40] 1598380666 1598380726 1598380786 1598380846 1598380906

> is.ts(x3)
[1] TRUE
```

as you can see, the result is identic but the format differs. rbind results in a `numeric` format and ts in a `time series` object.
I would like to have it in the same format of `x1` and `x2` (a `POSIXct` format) but I can't figure out how. Searching for it is quite difficult because the terms are so numerous in related topics..

edit: Finally, it isn't really about merging x1 and x2 together. Instead, I want to create a `POSIXct` object beginning with `2020-08-25 18:20:21 CEST` and ending with `2020-08-25 18:41:46 CEST` but with `30 s` time deltas.

Comment: Do you want `c(x1, x2)` ?

Comment: interesting, the format is correct but it results in time stamps beginning from "2020-08-25 20:20:21 CEST", "2020-08-25 20:21:21 CEST" ..

Comment: For me the results are still in "UTC" and same as combination of `x1` and `x2`.

Comment: even more interesting now..  whyever it gets shifted by two hours in my case. And the time delta is a minute, not 30 s? Ah, I realized that it combines them but doesn't really merge. I guess that's not an issue as I can probably re-order. But why is 20:20:21 instead of 18:20.21 ?

Comment: So if you need to create a 30-second sequence do you need `seq(min(x1), max(x1), '30 sec')`

Comment: awesome.. so easy. Thanks a lot! Could you post it an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a 30-second sequence from minimum value in `x1` and maximum value in `x2`.

```
x3 <- seq(min(x1), max(x2), '30 sec')
x3
# [1] "2020-08-25 18:20:21 UTC" "2020-08-25 18:20:51 UTC" "2020-08-25 18:21:21 UTC"
# [4] "2020-08-25 18:21:51 UTC" "2020-08-25 18:22:21 UTC" "2020-08-25 18:22:51 UTC"
# [7] "2020-08-25 18:23:21 UTC" "2020-08-25 18:23:51 UTC" "2020-08-25 18:24:21 UTC"
#[10] "2020-08-25 18:24:51 UTC" "2020-08-25 18:25:21 UTC" "2020-08-25 18:25:51 UTC"
#...
```